# Angular ngStyle - binding dynamic and static css attributes

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to combine the styles into one `[ngStyle]` binding but it keeps coming up with template errors.

Here's the working version, separated styles:

```
 <i [ngStyle]="{'background-color':getColorInitials(dataItem)}" 
                        style= "display: inline-flex; 
                                height: 30px; 
                                width: 30px;
                                border-radius: 50%;
                                border: white; 
                                border-style: solid; 
                                border-width: 1px;" >
```

However, this throws template errors. Can it be done ?

```
    <i [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color':getColorInitials(dataItem),
                                    'display': 'inline-flex',
                                    'height': '30px',
                                    'width': '30px',
                                    'border-radius': '50%'',
                                    'border': 'white',
                                    'border-style': 'solid',
                                    'border-width': '1px' }" >
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

use `borderRadius` instead of `border-radius` and the same for other hyphenated styles.

Comment: oh okay. That's using Angular's attrib names. I'll give that a try.

Comment: also you have an extra `'` after `'border-radius': '50%'',`